# MySQL - Update column with DATEADD on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, dateadd

I am trying to update my `created_at` (DATETIME) column in my database table with a new value, based on another column - 30 days prior to the `delivery_estimate` (DATE) column.

I have tried the below but I get an error in my syntax, saying DATEADD does not exist:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET created_at = DATEADD(day, -30, delivery_estimate)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: DATE_ADD() seems to be for mysql

Comment: Yes, Mysql, apologies

Answer (score 0):

The correct name for the function in MySql is [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), but you also use [SQL Server syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for it.
Change to this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET created_at = DATE_ADD(delivery_estimate, INTERVAL -30 day)
```

or simpler:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET created_at = delivery_estimate - INTERVAL 30 day
```